# random numbers between 1 and -1 in a 2D lattice

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have to make an assignment called **"The 2D Grid"** if you have heard of it?

The first task is to make a `2D lattice`, and the question goes:

Come up with a way to define a **square 2D list** (or *Numpy* `array`) containing randomly distributed values of -1 or 1.

I have used this:

```
np.random.randint(1, size = (6,6))
```

but how can I get numbers between 1 and -1 ?

Comment: Do you want numbers *between* `-1` and `1`, or do you want each entry in the resulting array to be *either* `-1` or `1`?  If the latter, you're going in the right direction: try replacing `np.random.randint(1, ...)` with `np.random.randint(2, ...)` as a first step.  (And then figure out how to convert the `0`s and `1`s to `-1`s and `1`s.)

Comment: Sorry i meant 1 or -1 yes. i did try that but now i have random 1s and 0s,i have just started this programing so i don't really know how to change the 0s so i only have 1s and -1s. hope you can help thanks

Comment: Okay, next hint: do you know how to multiply every element of a NumPy array by 2?  If so, do that to your `randint` result: you've now got an array containing `2`s and `0`s.  I'll leave the last step for you to figure out. :-)

Comment: i called my lattice for Lat_2D, then i printed lat_2D * 2 but i still can not see how i should turn the 0s into 1s or the 2s into 1s again ? :D